# forms as html and pdf

Tags: c#, html, pdf

I would create many forms with different outputs but i wish to design the form only once.

**First - HTML:**

- the form must be displayed in
  Internet Explorer
- the values (the user fills out the
  form) must be saved in a database
- the form must be displayed with
  the previus saved values in Internet
  Explorer

**Second - PDF:**

- the form must be exported as pdf
  with the previus saved values

**Requirements:**

- desing the form only once
- display+edit as html
- display as pdf

**Optional:**

- support for javascript on client-side
  for validation

I'm not sure whats the best way.

I could use libarys/tools like wkhtmltopdf or dompdf but i'm not sure if whether this also supports filled out html-form.
Imo XSL, XSLT and XSL:FO isn't an option because, if i understand that right i must create an XSL:FO for HTML-Output and one for PDF-Output.

What does you think?

Comment: you may be on the right track.....

Comment: The product I work on is called [Liquid Office](http://www.cardiff.com/products/liquidoffice/index.html).  It does all that (and more), but is probably overkill (workflow, BPM, all that jazz).  And expen$$$ive.  I'm not familiar with any smaller-scale competitors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it could be useful for all your points, but Crystal Reports files (.rpt) can be filled then exported quite well to Pdf, html or Word. It can take some time to get it working though (at work we use the version integrated in VS2008)...

Comment: But i need the Crytal Reports plugin for ie to filled them in the browser ?! This isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Stimulsoft.Web](http://www.stimulsoft.com/ReportsWeb.aspx) gels a lot with C# and you can export to anything + you can buy the sourcecode also,less expensive.

Comment: I don't whant to create Reports. I whant to create forms with inputs, radios, checkboxes, textareas ...

Comment: you could extend the code,any way,adobe pdf has a pdf form wizard which can be used distribute to a recepient list and it can store the data and be exported to a csv file, or InfoPath Forms Services